# knockoutjs with jQuery dialog not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a text box that is added each time a link is pressed, then when I press a details link next to each text box it should show a jQuery Dialog. I found something on stack overflow but can't make it work with my model. here is the jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/SuperJohn/se7kC/1/

This is the HTML:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'page-template', data: form.pages()[designer.pageId()] }"></div>
<script type="text/html" id="page-template">
    <div>
        <div id="fields" data-bind="template: { name: $root.designer.template.field, foreach: $data.fields }"></div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.designer.add.field.text">Text Box</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</script> 

<script type="text/html" id="field-nav">
    <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.editDetails">Details</a>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="text-template">
    <div>
        <div data-bind="template: { name: 'field-nav' }"></div>
    <label data-bind="text: $data.title"></label>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.valText" />
        <div data-bind="jqDialog: {autoOpen: false, modal: true}, template: {name: 'textDetails', data: $parent.selectedTool, if: $parent.selectedTool}, openDialog: $parent.selectedTool"></div>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="textDetails">
    <div data-bind="attr: {id: $data.id}">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Field</legend>
            <div>
            <label>Label</label>
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.title" />
        </div>
    </fieldset> 
    <button data-bind="jqButton: {}, click: $root.accept">Accept</button>
    <button data-bind="jqButton: {}, click: $root.cancel">Cancel</button>           
    </div>
</script>
```

This is the model JS:

```
function PageForm(id) {
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
this.fields = ko.observableArray([]);
}

function DesignerForm(id) {
this.pages = ko.observableArray([new PageForm(id)]);
}

var ViewModel = function ()
{
    var self = this;

self.form = new DesignerForm(0);

ko.bindingHandlers.jqDialog = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};

            //handle disposal
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            $(element).dialog("destroy");
        }); 

        //dialog is moved to the bottom of the page by jQuery UI. Prevent initial pass of ko.applyBindings from hitting it
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(element).dialog(options);  
        }, 0);
        }
    };

//custom binding handler that opens/closes the dialog
ko.bindingHandlers.openDialog = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (value) {
            $(element).dialog("open");
    } else {
        $(element).dialog("close");
    }
        }
    };

//custom binding to initialize a jQuery UI button
ko.bindingHandlers.jqButton = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};

    //handle disposal
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
        $(element).button("destroy");
    }); 

    $(element).button(options);  
    }    
};

self.selectedTool = ko.observable();
self.editDetails = function(detailsToEdit) {
    self.selectedTool(detailsToEdit);
};

self.accept = function() {
        self.selectedTool().accept();
    self.selectedTool("");
},

self.cancel = function() {
    self.selectedTool().cancel();
    self.selectedTool("");
}

self.designer = {
    "pageId": ko.observable(0),
    "add":
        {
        "field":
    {
        "text": function ()
        {
            var pg = self.designer.pageId();
        var idx = self.form.pages()[pg].fields().length;

        var fld = {
                        "id": idx,
            "type": "text",
            "title": "Textbox Label",
            "valText": ""
        };
        self.form.pages()[pg].fields.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(fld));
        }
    }
        },  
    "template": {
        "field": function (item)
    {
        // check for knockout bug
        if (typeof item.type == 'function') {
                    return item.type() + '-template';
        } else {
            return item.type + '-template';
        }
    }
    }    
};  
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: Change the `$parent` usages on `jqDialog` to `$root`

Comment: yes you were right, now is working, well it has a couple of other issues but I can deal with those. Thanks